# Testing for a PHP Closure without referring to the Closure internal class

Tags: php, closures

The [PHP manual for anonymous functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) (ie, Closures) states that:

> Anonymous functions are currently implemented using the Closure class. This is an implementation detail and **should not be relied upon**.

*(Emphasis is my own)*

Is it possible to test a variable, such that the test returns true only if the variable is a Closure, **without referring to the Closure class**?

In other words, how can I rewrite the following such that it will raise an error when `$bar` is anything but an anonymous function:

```
function foo(Closure $bar) {
    $bar();
}
```

EDIT: Based on the answers received, here is an example test.

Notes:

1. It seems there is no way to differentiate between Functors and Closures, and that 
   the test is probably just as 'implementation specific' as using the Closure class.
2. The (seemingly obvious) `ReflectionFunction::isClosure()` method seems to be be almost useless: by the time you've done the checks required to make sure that ReflectionFunction can actually be instantiated (can't take a Class except for a Closure), you've eliminated all other options.
3. In 5.3.0 you ReflectionClass($closure)->hasMethod('__invoke') returned false, so this could be used as a test against Functors, however (I'm told) this has changed since. This highlights the frailty of the solution too.
4. Follow up from [Gordon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/208809/gordon) - As of PHP 5.4 you can rely on Closure being a Closure: [php.net/manual/en/class.closure.php](http://php.net/manual/en/class.closure.php)

Code:

```
/**
 * Return true if and only if the passed argument is a Closure.
 */
function testClosure($a) {
    // Must be Callback, Labmda, Functor or Closure:
    if(!is_callable($a)) return false;

    // Elminate Callbacks & Lambdas
    if(!is_object($a)) return false;

    // Eliminate Functors
    //$r = new ReflectionFunction($a); <-- fails if $a is a Functor
    //if($r->isClosure()) return true;

    return false;
}
```

Test case:

```
//////////// TEST CASE /////////////

class CallBackClass {
    function callBackFunc() {
    }
}

class Functor {
    function __invoke() {
    }
}

$functor = new Functor();
$lambda = create_function('', '');
$callback = array('CallBackClass', 'callBackFunc');
$array = array();
$object = new stdClass();
$closure = function() { ; };

echo "Is it a closure? \n";
echo "Closure: " . (testClosure($closure) ? "yes" : "no") . "\n";
echo "Null: "  . (testClosure(null) ? "yes" : "no") . "\n";
echo "Array: " . (testClosure($array) ? "yes" : "no") . "\n";
echo "Callback: " . (testClosure($callback) ? "yes" : "no")  . "\n";
echo "Labmda: " .(testClosure($lambda) ? "yes" : "no") . "\n";
echo "Invoked Class: " . (testClosure($functor) ? "yes" : "no")  . "\n";
echo "StdObj: " . (testClosure($object) ? "yes" : "no") . "\n";
```

-

Comment: What about functions created using `create_function`, the poor man's anonymous functions from before PHP 5.3? What about objects that can be `__invoke()`d?

Comment: I'm specifically interested in whether you can test for a Closure ("...returns true only if the variable is a Closure...")

Comment: My question to you is why would you want to distinguish between a functor (or any callback at that point) and a closure?  In 5.3, there's no difference from your point of view (since you can't rebind anything), so what does it matter?  If it passes `is_callable()`, then why isn't that enough???

Comment: **As of PHP 5.4 you can rely on Closure being a Closure: http://php.net/manual/en/class.closure.php**

Comment: @Gordon thanks for the follow up! I'll add it above.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can also use

[`ReflectionFunctionAbstract::isClosure`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionfunctionabstract.isclosure.php) — Checks if closure

Example:

```
$poorMansLambda = create_function('', 'return TRUE;');
$rf = new ReflectionFunction($poorMansLambda);
var_dump( $rf->isClosure() ); // FALSE

$lambda  = function() { return TRUE; };   
$rf = new ReflectionFunction($lambda);
var_dump( $rf->isClosure() ); // TRUE

$closure = function() use ($lambda) { return $lambda(); };    
$rf = new ReflectionFunction($closure);
var_dump( $rf->isClosure() ); // TRUE
```

Note that the above will only return `TRUE` for PHP 5.3 Lambdas and Closures. If you just want to know whether an argument can be used as a callback, `is_callable` will perform better.

---

**EDIT** If you want to include Functors as well, you can do *([as of PHP 5.3.3](http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=52057))*

```
$rf = new ReflectionObject($functorOrClosureOrLambda);
var_dump( $rf->hasMethod('__invoke') ); // TRUE
```

or

```
method_exists($functorOrClosureOrLambda, '__invoke');
```

with the latter being the faster alternative.

A `Closure` instance is basically just a class that has an `__invoke` function which you fed the method body on the fly. But since this is testing for an implementation detail, I'd say it is as unreliable as testing for the `Closure` Class Name.

---

**EDIT** Since you mention you cannot reliably test via the Reflection API due to it raising an error when passing a Functor to `ReflectionFunctionAbstract::isClosure`, try if the following solution suits your needs:

```
function isClosure($arg)
{
    if(is_callable($arg, FALSE, $name)) {
        is_callable(function() {}, TRUE, $implementation);
        return ($name === $implementation);
    }
}
```

This will check if the passed argument is callable. The `$name` argument stores the callable name. For closures, this is currently `Closure::__invoke`. Since this will be the same for any Closures/Lambdas, we can compare the name of the passed argument against an arbitrary other Closure/Lambda. If they are equal, the argument must be a Closure/Lambda. Determining the callable name at runtime has the added benefit that you dont have to hardcode assumptions about the implementation details into your sourcecode. Passing a functor will return `FALSE`, because it wont have the same callable name. Since this does not rely on the Reflection API, it is also likely a bit faster.

The above could be more elegantly written as

```
function isClosure($arg) {
    $test = function(){};
    return $arg instanceof $test;
}
```

Comment: Nice, I likes me some reflection.

Comment: Nice. Will this approach get past his "implementation detail" problem? I guess I'm really asking if isClosure checks for class Closure.

Comment: @webbiedave - that doesn't really matter, since I'd assume that an implementation change to Closures would be replaced in ReflectionFunction

Comment: @webbiedave it's an API call, so you dont have to bother about it's implementation details and can rely on the devs to update the Reflection API whenever they update the class used for Closures/Lambdas. But since [I dont see any hardcoded classname in the sourcecode](http://svn.php.net/viewvc/php/php-src/trunk/ext/reflection/php_reflection.c?revision=304935&view=markup), I'd say it determines it somehow differently (`ZEND_ACC_CLOSURE`) anyway.

Comment: @Gordon - almost, but not quite. How do you test between a StdObj, an __invoke-able object and a Closure?

Comment: @Hamish a Functor is technically not a Closure since you have to implement the magic `__invoke` at the concrete class level. I couldn't find an `is_invokable` in the Reflection API though. Otherwise I had listed it above.

Comment: @Gordon - yeah, but the input type is unknown. Let me elaborate: if it is a Functor, you can use ReflectionClass and hasMethod - no problem. The final case, then, is StdClass (or any non invokable class). StdClass and Closures are both Objects (so is_object == true), however you can't call ReflectionFunction on StdClass ("expects parameter 1 to be string"). So, this raises an error, which is a partial solution, but not a clean test.

Comment: @Hamish for testing whether a method exists in an object via Reflection, you'd have to use [ReflectionClass::hasMethod](http://de2.php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.hasmethod.php) but faster would be `method_exists`. See my update.

Comment: @Gordon - interestingly, method_exists($closure, '__invoke') returns true, but new ReflectionClass($closure)->hasMethod('__invoke') returns false.

Comment: @Hamish try `ReflectionObject` instead. I dont know the inner workings of Closure exactly. You'd have to look into the trunk linked in the comments above

Comment: @Gordon same result (of course, because ReflectionObject inherits hasMethod from ReflectionClass).

Comment: @Hamish `$rf = new ReflectionObject(function() { return TRUE; }); var_dump($rf->hasMethod('__invoke'));` gives `TRUE` for me on PHP5.3.3 on Win7

Comment: @Gordon ah, 5.3.0 gives me FALSE. Ok, so what other was is there to test the difference between a Functor and Closure? You can't instantiate ReflectionFunction with a Functor.

Comment: @Hamish I'd say you got all the information to solve your problem now. Use any of the above or a combination thereof.

Comment: @Gordon How cryptic. Since they both report an __invoke method, you can't use ReflectionFunction, they're both callable and they're both objects, I'll take it to mean that it can't be done, and that in any regard, a solution like this is likely to be far MORE implementation-reliant that just using the Closure class name.

Comment: @Hamish I'm not being cryptic. I just dont see what else I should answer to you except for what I already did. The above solutions will let you distinguish between Closure/Lambda and Functors and other objects. `isClosure` does not rely on implementation details. `hasMethod`/`method_exists` does but on a lesser scale than `is_a` or `instanceof` Closure (which would not tell you if it's a Functor anyway, in which case you want `isClosure` again). I dont understand what else you are looking for.

Comment: @Gordon thanks for your comments - I'm not trying to be difficult, but I've pointed out why those solutions don't work. In order: 1. isClosure is only useful if you're able to create a ReflectionFunction object, but if you try to do this with a Functor you raise an error. I suppose I could catch the error, that defeats the purpose. Therefore isClosure can't be used. 2. hasMethod returns true for Closures (see your own comments!) and for Functors so can't be used to distinguish the two. 3. is_a or instanceof rely on the Closure class name, which I'm specifically trying to avoid.

Comment: @Hamish ok, like I said, I had a hard time understanding what your actual aim was. Now I get it. See my update above for another possible solution.

Answer (score 1):

[`is_callable`](http://php.net/is_callable) and `!is_array` might help you along. Note that you cannot rely on PHP's type hinting/checking this way, since you would have to check the variable inside the function and throw something, e.g. an `InvalidArgumentException` yourself.

Comment: +1 though it should be noted that this `is_callable` will return `TRUE` for any callables, not just Closures.

Comment: @Gordon: quite right, I was adding that as a comment to the original question while you posted this. :-)